# How to remove all traces of a package on uninstallation?

Tags: package-management, dpkg, uninstall

I've developed a package that I'm manually installing on Ubuntu systems (using `apt`). When uninstalling using:

```
sudo dpkg --purge <package-name>
```

I'm getting the warnings:

```
dpkg: warning: while removing <package-name>, directory '/opt/<package-name>' not empty so not removed 
dpkg: warning: while removing <package-name>, directory '/var/log/<package-name>' not empty so not removed
```

I would like to cleanly uninstall all the files from the system, and the directories I'm getting the warning for are only created by/used by my package. Is there a way to force-remove them (and is that a bad idea)?

I've thought about removing the directories in my package's postrm script but I'm not sure if that's the best approach. Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `postrm` to force the removal of the folder, but you need to be aware of two possible issues:

1. `postrm` is called during a `dpkg --remove` and during `dpkg --purge`, and your folder will always be removed.
2. If you write to a shared folder you will also remove other applications using that folder.

In order to prevent Issue 2, you could first remove all your files and then check if directory is empty and only then remove it.

If Issue 1 is not a concern to you, you can force the removal but in order to differentiate between remove and purge in postrm,  in your case you can:

```
if [ "$1" = "purge" ]; then
rmdir -R  /path/to/directory
fi
```